# WSGIDaemonProcess causes 'You don't have permission error'

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu-16.04, mod-wsgi

Hello I am trying to deploy my django application on digital ocean server. I did run the application inside a virtual environment and it all worked fine. But I want my domain to point to my application and followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial. But the problem is when the apache conf file is edited with the following code i get the error.

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.

This is how my directly looks

```
    +root
    +myproject
        +myproject
            settings.py
            urls.py
            wsgi.py
        +static
        manage.py
    +myprojectenv
```

Here is my WSGI.py

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Here is my Apache Default conf file 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

#ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
#DocumentRoot /var/www/html

Alias /static /home/user/alpha/static
<Directory /home/user/alpha/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /static /home/root/myproject/static
<Directory /home/root/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/root/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/home/root/myproject/myprojectenv python-path=/home/root/myproject
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/root/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

I am not experience enough to find out what is causing the error. If i remove below lines in the apache conf file. I get Ubuntu home page when i try to access my server

```
 WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/home/root/myproject/myprojectenv python-path=/home/root/myproject
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/root/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Python code will run as the Apache user. As a result it likely will not have access to files under home directories as they don't have permissions on them that allows access by others.

You should move stuff from out of the home directories and put it under somewhere like `/var/www/project`.

See:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#access-rights-of-apache-user

Comment: did exactly what you said. but now the problem is gateway timeout error is thrown. if i remove the WSGIdaemonprocess config in the 000-default-conf file. it shows the ubuntu landing page when i access the ip. any clue what mistake is made here ?

Comment: Add ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}``. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api You are likely using some package which doesn't work in sub interpreters and it is blocking.